# Rails: Mirror a controller with different paths and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

Using: Rails 3.1.1

I have a controller/model/view called Category that is built up on a tree category system using acts_as_tree & parent_id's. In the Category#Show-view I show a lot of different information: name, description, color, etc.

I call upon Category#Show with `category_path(@category)`  # => e.g. domain.com/category/car

Now I want to create a Store-view that needs:

- Unique paths
- Unique views

but using all other attributes from the Category controller, like the same database tables.

I want to be able to use `store_path(@store) # => domain.com/stores/car` and access all the data from the Category car-object but show it using the Store#Show-view.

So, basically I want to echo/mirror Category and view the same data in a different manner and call that from a different path. If `@category.color # => blue` I want `@store.color # => blue` as well.

I will only use Store with #show and #index (no updated/destroy/edit etc).

It feels like this should be something related to inheriting but I don't really know where to start or what to do. Could you please bump me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the easiest way of handling this was by just by just acts as if I was in the CategoryController (while in the Store controller) and use @store = Category.find(params[:id]) and then use @store.

Answer (score 0):

StoreController can simple extend CategoryController.